# Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this issue after updating my android studio to **gradle:3.0.0** , This error getting at time of my app MAP zoom and my emulator close directly with above error code